# As a DM how do I make a Macro for monster attacks and Save Check in R20

Tags: roll20

I wanna make a Macro that uses @Selected but I dun't know how to put it in a way that whenever I've selected a monster when I press the attack1 button in the Bar the monster I am selecting will roll a Dice corresponding to it's weapon on attack1.

For example

When I selected Basilisk then pressed attack1 macrokey/button, it will roll for the bite attack like show on the image below. But I wanna make the button be universal to any monster I am selecting.

[image]

Answer (score 9):

What you are looking for are [Token Actions](https://wiki.roll20.net/Token_Actions), which will allow you to create macros that will only apply to tokens. The *variable* to access the selected token is called **selected**, which will allow you to obtain stats and variables from the selected token. There are [several examples here](https://wiki.roll20.net/Macros#Using_a_Selected_Token_with_a_Macro), like:

> /roll 1d20 + @{selected|Attack}

Check out some other [useful macros for d20-based games](https://wiki.roll20.net/Useful_Macros#D20_Based_Systems).